# HTML Add To Calendar Button

Tags: html, css, button, calendar, addition

I would like to code a button that allows to add an event to a calendar just by using HTML and CSS. I saw similar solutions including Javascript code but I am working on a solution that doesn't allow JS code in his "raw text" section.

Is that even possible ?

Comment: What kind of calendar? Google Calendar?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so, HTML and CSS are just to format a page.

Comment: Even if we use the same things than for a button for telephone or for email for example ?

Comment: What kind of calendar?

Comment: For any calendar, the aim is to add an event to your calendar, no matter if you are google Agenda for Apple Calendar etc... I think I should look for how to do it with ICS file of the event. But how to create an ICS file ?

Comment: Create an appointment yourself, then click file and save as type iCalendar format in outlook.

Comment: You can add `<a href="webcal://...">Text</a>` and style the anchor tag as a button.